# Ruby .include? method is not accepted as a valid method

Tags: ruby, methods, runtime-error

I have this Ruby code in a script:

```
$dev_input=gets.chomp.downcase!
    if $dev_input.include? "/"
        check_developer_commands()
    else
        puts ">>Invalid Command<<"
        continuing_dev_mode()
    end
```

The problem is, whenever I try and run the script containing this, I get an error spat back at me that says :

```
dev_continue_main.rb:3:in 'continuing_dev_mode': undefined method 'include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any idea what this error might be? I'm pretty sure that this is the proper way to use the .include? method. I've done some research, looked at tutorialspoint.com and some other sites, but they agree that this is the proper way to use this method.

I checked the error message and it confirmed that the third line in this script/my example is the source of the problem, so it's not some other instance of this method throwing an error.

Any thoughts? Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$dev_input` is `nil`. That stems from applying `downcase!` in defining `$dev_input`. I don't know why you want to possibly assign `nil` to `$dev_input`, and at the same time claim that calling `include?` on it is the right way. I don't get your intention for doing that, but if you instead had `$dev_input = gets.chomp.downcase`, then it wouldn't cause such error.

Comment: Alright! I'll give that a try. Why does calling .downcase! on it make it nil? Sorry I'm a bit new to Ruby.

Comment: @Leshy: the purpose of `downcase!` is to mutate the string in-place. Its return value is irrelevant, and `nil` is the standard way to indicate an irrelevant value in Ruby. More precisely: `downcase!` will return the downcased string if it actually did downcase something, and `nil` if there was nothing to do. This is all clearly spelled out in the documentation. So, the short answer to your question "Why does calling .downcase! on it make it nil?" is: because the documentation says so.

Comment: @Leshy, you should [read the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21). `downcase!` returns `nil` if no modification has been done to the string - ie, it was already lowercase.